# Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues how to fix this

Tags: android-studio

> 

Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

```
at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:121)
at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:71)
at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:19)
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.startApp(StartupUtil.java:303)
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:245)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:47)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

> 

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read this guide on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this exception, this is after I upgraded android studio 4.1, I could not open android studio and reported this error

```html
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.loadDescriptors()[Lcom/intellij/ide/plugins/IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl;
    at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:121)
    at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:71)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:19)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.startApp(StartupUtil.java:303)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:245)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:47)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Later, I found that the root of the problem was actually that some plug-ins did not support higher versions, and then they couldn't start.

The solution is: go to this directory
C:\Users{user}\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins

Then copy all the folders or jar packages (in fact, the plug-ins you downloaded yourself), then delete the folders first, and then start android studio, if it can be started, then there is a problem with the plug-ins under this folder If it cannot be started, restore this file and continue to delete other files. If it is determined that there is a problem with the plug-in under this folder, delete one plug-in one plug-in, so that you can find out which plug-in has the problem through the loop, and delete it Ok